# pip install error: "Unknown archive format: .whl"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

I'm new to virtualenv (on windows).  I'm trying to use pip (1.5) install a local wheel file, but it is failing.

The command is:

```
pip install --no-index -f C:/Users/<User>/Download openpyxl
```

In the pip.log, I can see where it finds the correct file, but then doesn't try to install it:

```
  Skipping link file:///C:/Users/<User>/Download/openpyxl-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl; unknown archive format: .whl
```

I have wheel (version 0.22) install globally as well as in the virtual environment.  Any idea how I can get .whl to be a recognized format?

Comment: does `pip install C:/Users/<User>/Download/openpyxl-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` work?

Comment: No, that fails with a different error:

Comment: Ah, the error is thrown when `wheel` support has been disabled. What version of `setuptools` have you got installed?

Comment: @Martijn The error is ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'C:/Users/<User>/Download/openpyxl-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'at', ':/Users/<User>/Download/openpyxl-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl')

Comment: Then your `setuptools` is *definitely* too old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears wheel support is disabled.

Make sure that you have `setuptools` version 0.8 or newer installed, and that the `use-wheel` option is not set to `false` in `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`.

Upgrading `setuptools` is easy enough if `pip` is already working:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but note that older `virtualenv` versions can depend on older `setuptools` versions; you'll need to make sure that `virtualenv` is also up to date.

Comment: "Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools" - global version is setuptools-2.0.2-py2.7.egg.  So doesn't look like that is the problem.  [edit] Tried upgrade both globally and in virtualenv [/edit]

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: The checked the `pip` source code; the archive format is only unrecognized if `use_wheel` is set to `False`; it is only set to `False` if `pip` did not find a setuptools new enough (it'll issue a warning), *or* if specifically disabled.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: The fact that a direct install fails with a version spec parsing error is indicative that `pip` is not using the correct `setuptools` version, however.

Comment: Odd.  My virtual env has two setuptools folders in site-packages: "setuptools" and "setuptools-2.0.2-py2.7.egg-info".  setuptools.pth has "./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg" in it, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you have `distribute` installed at some point? It looks like some manual cleanup is required.

Comment: Looks like the issue was virtualenv.  I was on 1.9.1, and it looks like that installs the older setuptools.  I upgraded to 1.11 and recreated the virtualenvs and now .whl is working.  If you want to mention upgrade virtualenv, I would be glad to mark your answer correct.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: Indeed; virtualenv versions do set a version dependency. Sigh; I wish they didn't do that. :-)

Comment: This alone did not solve my problem. I finally made it work by `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 3):

I have bumped into the same problem with wheel when downloaded requirements with:

```
pip install --download /pip_mirror six django_debug_toolbar
dir2pi /pip_mirror/
```

and tried to install them with:

```
pip install six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Even though there is no any config at $HOME/.pip/pip.conf and

```
$ easy_install --version
setuptools 5.4.1
```

I still get:

> unknown archive format: .whl

I have managed to avoid the problem by adding `--no-use-wheel` like this, so got only tar.gz files (instead of .whl)

```
pip install --no-use-wheel --download /pip_mirror six django_debug_toolbar
dir2pi /pip_mirror/
```

After this `pip install --index-url=file:///pip_mirror/simple/ six` went without any problems

Comment: the parameter --no-use-wheel was exactly what i was looking for. thx

Comment: --no-use-wheel have been deprecated , https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171690/4683950