# Docker: no such option: --use-wheel

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, python-wheel

I'm trying to use Docker to create a dependency package for AWS Lambda using [this](https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda) repository, but whenever I try to run the build.sh file, I end up with the message:

> no such option: --use-wheel

Then when I try to use `pip install wheel` (outside of Docker), I'm told that it's already on my local machine, which it is. **How do I install Wheel in the Docker container?**

If it's helpful, this appears to be the line of code in build.sh that is giving the issue:

```
test -f /outputs/requirements.txt && pip install --use-wheel -r /outputs/requirements.txt
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue isn't due to missing dependencies ( `wheel` is installed in the `build.sh` script you referenced: https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda/blob/master/build.sh#L18 )

`use-wheel` was deprecated and no longer exists for `pip`.

You can achieve the same by omitting the `--use-wheel` entries from the script.  Take a look at the Python 3.6 PR on the linked repository:  https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda/pull/16/files#diff-0b83f9dedf40d7356e5ca147a077acb4

Comment: Okay, I tried replacing the original build.sh with the pull request that you linked to, but now I get the error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application` and I'm not sure how to update pip within Docker, assuming that's what I need to do? I'll also try just omitting the commands from the original build.sh and see if that helps.

Comment: It's working now. I simply deleted all instances of '--use-wheel', as you recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`--use-wheel` is [deprecated since pip 7](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id25) (in favor of `--only-binary`) and [removed since pip 10 beta 1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31).

To fix all scripts in a git repo:

`git grep -l -- --use-wheel | while read f; do sed -i -e 's|use-wheel|only-binary=:all:|g' ${f}; done`