# Unable to build Scikit learn packages with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I followed the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835842/docker-no-such-option-use-wheel) to build Scikit learn packages for AWS Lambda but I get the below error when I invoke the lambda function. I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows. Not sure why I am getting the below error message?

> {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sklearn.**check_build._check_build'\n___________________________________________________________________________\nContents of /var/task/sklearn/__check_build:\nsetup.py __pycache**               _check_build.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so\n__init__.py\n___________________________________________________________________________\nIt seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.\n\nIf you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget\nto build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or\n`make` in the source directory.\n\nIf you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your\nPython version, your operating system and your platform.", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this problem, this [post](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) may help you. In particular, try to add `dockerizePip: non-linux` under `pythonRequirements`.